# Django with multiple subdomains - sometimes renders incorrect template

Tags: python, django, subdomain

Bizarre:

I have two domains:

- www.domain.com
- app.domain.com

Both with individual settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py files (set up like this: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2010/10/19/run-multiple-websites-one-django-project/)

Sometimes--maybe 30% of the time--everything works fine. When I visit www.domain.com, I have pages such as /login, /contact, /join. It's a standard Django site.

app.domain.com will be a single page app, so its urls file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from .app_views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^.*$', index, name='app'),
]
```

So, any time a user visits app.domain.com or app.domain.com/foo or app.domain.com/anything, I want to render my index function.

Now, sometimes, I'll visit app.domain.com, and www.domain.com template will be rendered. Not only that, I'll have urls such as app.domain.com/login or app.domain.com/contact

Weird!

Even stranger, if I go back to www.domain.com, my app.domain.com index template is rendered!

If I refresh the page a few times, it will eventually get to the correct page, but seems random and unpredictable.

Has anyone encountered this before or know what's up?

Comment: sounds like a problem with caching to me

Comment: I thought so too, but I've been clearing my cache while testing...

Answer (score 1):

24 hours later.... lesson learned:

If you're using multiple WSGIDaemonProcesses in distinct VirtualHosts, properly configure WSGIProcessGroup. In this case, they should have mirrored the servername of the VirtualHost.